# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not a function (Vue.js, Electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, promise, electron

i am trying to animate some elements using anime.js with some promise functions, the problem is that the second function wont run once the previous one was successful.

```
<script>
import Splash from '../components/Splash.vue';
import Intro from '../components/Intro.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Splash,
    Intro,
  },
  mounted() {
  //This is the line of the error `const animateSplash = async () => {` 
    const animateSplash = async () => {
      const splashAnim = this.$anime({
        targets: '.logo',
        easing: 'cubicBezier(.5, .05, .1, .3)',
        keyframes: [
          { duration: 1000, opacity: 0 },
          { duration: 1000, opacity: 1 },
          { delay: 3000, duration: 500, opacity: 0 },
        ],
        complete(anim) {
          document.querySelector('.logo-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
        },
      }).finished;

      await Promise.all(splashAnim);
    };

    animateSplash().then(() => {
      const introAnim = this.$anime({
        targets: '.intro-wrapper',
        easing: 'cubicBezier(.5, .05, .1, .3)',
        keyframes: [
          { duration: 1000, opacity: 0 },
          { duration: 1000, opacity: 1 },
        ],
        begin(anim) {
          document.querySelector('.intro-wrapper').style.display = 'flex';
        },
      }).finished;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

I am getting an error

`Home.vue?76f2:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not a function` which again points to `const animateSplash = async () => {`. But it runs the first animation which is `splashAnim`.

Comment: It is not clear out of your code what is `this.$anime`, i can't see such key in your object, so it is `undefined`

Comment: @DmitryReutov Its working fine, its a prototype of anime.js attached to every vue instance

Comment: here is 90% questions are not worth to leave them. Do not worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

1. `Promise.all()` accepts Array. `splashAnim` appears not to be Array. (as already acknowledged)
2. If `splashAnim` is Promise (or even just a thenable), then simply `return splashAnim;`.
3. If you are dealing with Promises, you can (and arguable should) avoid those cumbersome `begin` and `complete` callbacks.

As far as I can tell (and assuming that `this.$anime().finished` does indeed return Promise), you are trying to do as follows:

```
export default {
    components: { Splash, Intro },
    mounted() {
        return this.$anime({
            'targets': '.logo',
            'easing': 'cubicBezier(.5, .05, .1, .3)',
            'keyframes': [
                { 'duration': 1000, 'opacity': 0 },
                { 'duration': 1000, 'opacity': 1 },
                { 'delay': 3000, 'duration': 500, 'opacity': 0 }
            ]
        }).finished
        .then(() => {
            document.querySelector('.logo-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.intro-wrapper').style.display = 'flex';
            return this.$anime({
                'targets': '.intro-wrapper',
                'easing': 'cubicBezier(.5, .05, .1, .3)',
                'keyframes': [
                    { 'duration': 1000, 'opacity': 0 },
                    { 'duration': 1000, 'opacity': 1 },
                ]
            }).finished;
        });
    }
};
```

Note that the two `return` statements allow the caller of `mounted()` to be informed, by way of Promise, of completion of the whole animation process.

Comment: @Areg, do you have evidence that `.finished` is not needed in the inner animation? My reasoning for including it was that to fully inform the caller of completion of the two animations, a Promise needs to be returned, and `.finished` appears to be required in order to return Promise. So either both occurrences of `.finished` are required or both are not required. Which is it? If I hear nothing, I'm rolling back.

Comment: Right - [it's an electon thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/finished), and is required for the reason given above ..... rolling back.

Comment: I tried this code without the last .finished and it worked fine

Comment: @Areg, it will work fine in itself but without the inner `.finished`, `mounted().then(...)`, in the caller, won't be cognizant of the second animation. Even if you don't propose to chain `.then()`, that inner `.finished` should be included.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was this one line which awaited for the promise

`await Promise.all(splashAnim);`

I changed it to

`await splashAnim;`

and it worked fine. This is a mistake because `Promise.all` should work with only with multiple promises and not one.

Comment: That was my first idea but then i though that finished can return several finished promises